# cannot run npm global modules on linux

Tags: linux, node.js, npm, linux-mint

Checkout the screenshot: [Linux terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFJIo.png)

I have installed the global modules using npm but I am not able to use it. For example I run the command "stylus -v" and the terminal replies me with nothing. I am not able to understand why this problem might be happening as I am new to linux.

Comment: are you using NVM?

Comment: try using nvm, it should fix it

Comment: Thanks! it was a problem with the version of node!